# Websites take a long time to load

Tags: firefox, internet

Websites in Ubuntu take a very long time to load. In Windows, it all works fine. The download speed is normal.

Here's a [video capture](http://www.kurah.net/hackersoft/out-2.ogv) to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you have a broken non-responding DNS server listed first in your network config. Check in `Network Manager`, or `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and look for `nameserver` lines.

Your ISP should give you DNS server entries which are in their own network and will be pretty fast for you - make sure you're using those; although given the speed it's currently working at, *any* working DNS server will probably be better :)

Comment: Google's set dns. does not work

Answer (score 0):

Windows make an heavy use of the cache when Ubuntu does not.

Probably you only need faster DNS or you can setup bind9 as "caching server" https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto and on the internet is plenty of lists of free public DNS servers http://www.google.com/search?q=public+dns